# Decrease propery of first found child element on a specific document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this MongoDB collection containing different documents like the ones I show down here.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0b456bf7a87830b4d20058"),
"type" : "vehicles"
"cars" : [ 
    {
        "color" : "red",
        "amount" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "color" : "green",
        "amount" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "color" : "blue",
        "amount" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "color" : "yellow",
        "amount" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find a document by `"_id" : ObjectId("5b0b456bf7a87830b4d20058")` and decrease one amount of `"cars"`, not caring if its color red, green, blue or yellow. In the example, `"red"` cars are already `0` so I shouldn't decrease it because I can't have a negative amount, so the update should look for the next element and update amount of `"green"` cars to `0`.

The next time I run the query, amounts of `"red"` and `"green"` cars would be `0`, so I should decrease amount of `"blue"` cars. If i run the query more times, it should decrease `"blue"` cars to `0` and then do the same with `"yellow"` until it reaches `0` too and finally, query would do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to define which array element should be updated. It simply takes first matching element of an array so you can define `$gt` condition to modify only those with `amount > 0`. [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html) can be used to decrease `amount` value

```
db.col.update({ _id: ObjectId("5b0b456bf7a87830b4d20058"), "cars.amount" : { $gt: 0 } }, { $inc: { "cars.$.amount": -1 } })
```

There will be no update when all `amounts` are zeros

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was right what I needed and it works perfectly.